# php print version number of curl

Tags: php, curl

I need to print curl version using this [documnts](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-version.php) :

```
<?PHP echo curl_version('version');?>
```

but my output is empty! how do can i print version number of curl?

Comment: error of string value

Comment: curl_version() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given

Comment: you must use : print_r(curl_version([int]), TRUE), or var_dump(curl_version([int])), while curl_version() return an associative array

Comment: strictly speaking: you can't print the version of curl, because you're not running curl, but you CAN print the version of **lib**curl, because you're running libcurl in your php installation :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
print_r(curl_version());    // remove your unexpected parameter
                            // also it returns an array , don't use echo.
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/w0wZct)**

**Edit after the comment**

```
$values=curl_version();
echo $values["version"];
```

P.S: Of course you need to have `cURL` installed and enabled first.

Comment: Your Code `print_r` display all array of curl version! but in my Q i need to print only version number.

Comment: Wow that would be very easy to extract from the array wont it?

Comment: Sure! my mean is your answer not complete for my Q. just this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$info = curl_version();
echo $info["version"];

?>
```